# What is inline-rendering in React router and how does it work with "render" inside a route/

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

Looking at the [docs](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/render-func), I'm confused on when to use `render` vs. `component` inside a router as the former doesn't remount the component but the latter does? When you leave a route and comeback, doesn't it always unmount the component and remount it? In what situation would you not remount it?

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to render a component with just the route props, then use **component**:

```
<Route path="/user/:username" component={ User } />
```

However, if you want to pass props to your component then you should NOT pass a function to **component**, like this:

```
<Route path="/user/:username" component={ (props) => <User example="something" { ...props } /> } />
```

You should instead use **render** to render the component with props:

```
<Route path="/user/:username" render={ (props) => <User example="something" { ...props } /> } />
```